# take user to a specific setting in app settings on android

Tags: android, settings, android-permissions

On my android app I want the user to turn off auto-revoke-permissions setting. however I have noticed that `IntentCompat.createManageUnusedAppRestrictionsIntent(activity, activity.packageName)` only opens app settings and then it is up to the user to scroll down find the appropriate setting and turn it off (this is on a pixel running android 12). Needless to say, this is terrible UX.

I would like that after the intent launches the the apps settings screen, it automatically scrolls down and gives focus to the setting the user should toggle.

I have seen some apps achieve this, specifically I recently installed a mock location provider (fakeGPS Location) that automatically launched developer options and had it scroll down to the set mock location provider part. I am not sure how they managed to do this (if adding action or extras to the intent) but it is clearly possible. I have googled this extensively but cant seem to find how they did it or if I could apply what they did to my use case. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "it is clearly possible" -- IMHO, not in any practical sense. You are welcome to use accessibility APIs to attempt to do what you describe. You should discuss your plans for this with qualified legal counsel. And, please bear in mind that there are tens of thousands of Android device models, with dozens upon dozens of variations of the screen that you are citing.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am currently trying to set this up using the accessibility API as I think that is what the app in question might have used. my fear is that otherwise the user might not understand what setting I want him to toggle. Do you maybe know of any alternative (less hacky) ways to achieve this? Also, while I have you, I have found it difficult to find out if it is even necessary for me to request this since for some devices this setting is not even visible and apparently not neede even if isAutoRevokeWhitelist=false as seen in this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172325509

Comment: "my fear is that otherwise the user might not understand what setting I want him to toggle" -- abusing accessibility APIs for non-accessibility roles may eventually land you in trouble. "or some devices this setting is not even visible" -- device manufacturers can and do change the Settings app however they see fit. How do you intend to get your accessibility solution to work across a wide range of devices? That is above and beyond the problems outlined in that issue.

Comment: @Commonsware Ok, so I will just assume that it is impossible to point the user to the right setting without abusing the accessibility API when it is present. And I will have to live with the fact that I have no way of finding out if the setting is present at all. my fallback solution is to simply declare a dummy background service as mentioned in the issue or create a jobScheduler that checks if permissions are granted regularly and prompts the user to re-grant them if revoked. not sure what other options I have. its imperative that my app keep its permissions and I know it ll rarely be opened

Comment: "its imperative that my app keep its permissions and I know it ll rarely be opened" -- FWIW, personally, I would focus on fixing the "rarely be opened" part. I would find ways to add value to the user experience such that many, if not most, users will *want* to open it once a month or more. AFAIK, "open" includes anything that is visible, so it's not just a launcher activity, but also includes app widgets and notification shade tiles.

Comment: @CommonsWare we are talking about an app that only will be used in emergency situations. the app in question provides a service to a different app that starts and stops that service, but only rarely. since the emergency situations that warrant the use of both apps only happen rarely I am afraid that when the very important, time critical, moment comes my app wont have the necessary permissions to do its job and provide its service.  here, the not being opened very frequently part is a consequence of the nature of the app and the not having its permissions revoked is an app critical feature

Comment: I have a hunch that that my app might already be whitelisted from permission revocation since on various devices the setting does not even appear. As I said my app already provides a service (a foreground service that is only rarely started and doesnt run for long) but when the need arises it needs to do its job reliably. from the google issue I mentioned it is not clear to me if this is already sufficient to whitelist my app. they talk about a background service and mine is a foreground one and not always running.

Comment: on my pixel running android 12 the setting to auto revoke permissions appears twice: once in general settings turned on and enabled and once in the permissions section turned off and disabled (which is confusing to me). What I find most frustrating is that the `isAutorevokeWitelisted` flag always returns false and I feel there is no good way to find out if I even need to prompt the user to toggle this setting or if the setting is present at all. I also dont know if I can rely on the fact that my app will be whitelisted on all devices, if it even is on those I tested so far